# Displaying pagination

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, report, ireport

I have a report for sales in *iReports 3.7.6*

For the properties of the sold items I have "stretch relative to tallest object" and it repeats depending on the number of items sold.

The thing is, whether the number of items sold, or if the description of a single item is long enough that the report breaks into two pages, the field for "page X of Y" will not display on the first page, only on the last page, this happens regardless of "page x of y" being set on the Page Footer band or Last Page Footer band.

Shouldn´t the report save some space for the footer regardless of the Detail 1 band stretching into a second page? Or is there any way to order reports to do so?

Comment: Can you show the code snippet how are you doing this. For just your info check whether you have added evaluationTime="Report"

Comment: Page X of Y is actually divided into two fields once you select it from the pallete, "Page X" eveluation time is set to NOW while "of Y" is set to REPORT. I read about how that should be how it is done in order to display both current page and for it to show up on the very last page, it is also the default evaluation times for both fields.